# How to save data in a UITableview with core data- Swift code

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsuserdefaults

I'm wondering if someone can show me how to save the data in tableview with core data?

I have an app that is required to store a lot of user input in table view. I have been using UserDefault which I shouldn't. I have not imported core data yet cause I don't know how to use it to store data from user input and fetch the data from core data to display it in table view.

I saved user input into an array which is `logs`.

```
var logs = [String]()
var userData = false

@IBOutlet weak var TableLogs: UITableView!
@IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {
     let a = (StartKm.text! as NSString).intValue
     let b = (StartKm.text! as NSString).floatValue
     let sum = a * 2
     let sumb = b * 2

    overallTrip.text = "\(sum)"
    overallTrip.text = "\(sumb)"


   let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: userData)
    userData = true
    UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "userData")

    if StartKm.text == "" {
        StartKm.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }else{
         StartKm.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
         logs.append(overallTrip.text!)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(overallTrip.text, forKey: "overall")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }

    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"FYI", message:"You have \(5000 - sumb)KM left", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)



internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: nil)

    cell.textLabel?.text = logs[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        logs.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(logs, forKey: "overall")
    }
    TableLogs.reloadData()
}


func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


    if(segue.identifier == "CarKmd") {
 //     var vc = segue.destination as! CarKm
        let viewcontroller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CarKmd")

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller!, animated: true)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hey, Dadummn have you tried reading articles about it, if no I recommend go through this link and make a demo, this will surely help.   https://www.raywenderlich.com/7569-getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial

Comment: Unrelated but why do you archive a single Bool (`userData`)? That's overkill. Just write it to `UserDefaults` with `UserDefaults.standard.set(userData, forKey: "userData")`

Comment: @ShivamGaur I have not seen it yet! I will have a read through it thanks!

Comment: @vadian I dont remember exactly why haha. There was an error if I remember, that's why I had to archive it